# Scala find horizontal and vertical words when given a map of symbols and their positions

Tags: scala, parsing, dictionary

I'm currently working on reading data in functional programming. I'm given a Map[Vec2, Char] and i have to extract horizontal and vertical words. Coordinates start at top left side. Example input could be like this:

```
All data is in form of Map[Vec2, Char]
For example we have our Map info like this:
'-' means empty space here
-------------
-SOMETHING---
--A------A---
--T------MAN-
--S------E---
-------------

I need to get:
Something(1,1) - Horizontal
Oats(2,1) - Vertical
Game(9,1) - Vertical
Man(9,3) - Horizontal
```

I've achieved this by building a grid out of my map. Then Regex comes into play. But how do I do this without implementing strings? Any Ideas?

-Thank you so much!! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?
Note that I would never use something like this in production - while it is "functional", it isn't efficient and its definitely not readable.

```
val in = Map[(Int, Int), Char](
  (1, 1) -> 'S',
  (1, 2) -> 'O',
  (1, 3) -> 'M',
  (1, 4) -> 'T',
  (1, 5) -> 'H',
  (1, 6) -> 'I',
  (1, 7) -> 'N',
  (1, 8) -> 'G',
  (2, 2) -> 'A',
  (3, 2) -> 'T',
  (4, 2) -> 'S',
  (2, 8) -> 'A',
  (3, 8) -> 'M',
  (4, 8) -> 'E',
  (3, 9) -> 'A',
  (3,10) -> 'N',
).toList

val rows = in.map(entry => entry._1._1 -> (entry._1._2 -> entry._2)).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sorted)
val cols = in.map(entry => entry._1._2 -> (entry._1._1 -> entry._2)).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sorted)

def groupWords(charsAndOffsets: List[(Int, Char)]): List[(Int, String)] = charsAndOffsets.foldLeft(List.empty[(Int, String)]) {
  case (Nil, (col, char)) =>
    List(col -> char.toString)

  case ((lastCol, lastWord) :: prevWords, (col, char)) if lastCol + lastWord.length == col =>
    (lastCol, lastWord + char) :: prevWords

  case ((lastCol, lastWord) :: prevWords, (col, char)) =>
    (col, char.toString) :: (lastCol, lastWord) :: prevWords
}.filter(_._2.length > 1)

val wordsInRows = rows.mapValues(groupWords).filter(_._2.nonEmpty)
val wordsInCols = cols.mapValues(groupWords).filter(_._2.nonEmpty)

println(wordsInRows)
println(wordsInCols)
```

The program prints words in rows and words in cols as follows:

```
Map(1 -> List((1,SOMTHING)), 3 -> List((8,MAN)))
Map(2 -> List((1,OATS)), 8 -> List((1,GAME)))
```

Comment: Yeah, It seems quite silly, this task, but it's just an exercise. Thank you for you solution, I will def check it out!! ^^